# Eclipse doesnt seem to like my sdkversion requirements

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-2.2-froyo

I have in my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
                android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
```

I want to allow 2.2 to run my app but i have to have targetsdkversion 13 for admob to work. But eclipse is saying: " Attribute minSdkVersion (8) is lower than the project target API level (13)" and wont even show the avd's for anything below 3.2... but that didn't happen until just a little while ago. I didnt change anything there. whats happening? i've tried to clean it but that didnt help.

Comment: I used to see the warning in the older version of eclipse and the ADT, but since moving to Indigo and the newer android plug in I no longer get that, it was just annoying.  The second part sounds weird, so are you saying that you no longer can see any build targets when you right click on properties then select android?

Comment: That's happened to me too sometimes, but if you start your <3.2 emulator from the AVD Manager itself and then try to run your app you should be able to select it.

Comment: @Idistic create an answer, that fixed it.

Comment: Done, glad it was that simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to see the warning in the older version of eclipse and the ADT, but since moving to Indigo and the newer android plug in I no longer get that, it was just annoying but did not cause any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

It's just be a warning. If you run your app, it should run on any devices from SDK version 8 to 13. Are you not able to generate the apks, and run it?

Comment: I can run them but the devices <3.2 stopped showing up. I'll update eclipse and see what happens. Im running helios.